# generalized the method used by three different service implementation an using generics

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, refactoring

The below method is utilized by three different services and in future it is possible that other implementations will also be utilized the same, currently the method is not centralized, it is boiler plated as it is present in each service implementation. I am looking for a way to make it centralized using generics or any other suggested solution.

```
public void persistImageDetailsV2() {
        String bucketKey = null;
        String modelCode = null;
        List<S3Object> objList = new ArrayList<>();
        String bucketName = s3BucketDetails.getBucketName();
        String bucketPath = s3BucketDetails.getMsilBucketPrefix();
        log.info("[{}]:Intializing the required attributes: Bucket name [{}] and Bucket path [{}] ", appName,
                bucketName, bucketPath);
        try {
            fillMap();
            List<ModelCode> modelCodes = layoutRepository.findDistinctAllBy();
            List<String> modelCodePresent = modelCodes.stream().map(ModelCode::getModelCode)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            List<CommonPrefix> allKeysInDesiredBucket = listAllKeysInsideBucket(bucketName, bucketPath);
            List<String> s3ModelCodes = allKeysInDesiredBucket.stream().map(CommonPrefix::prefix)
                    .map(s -> new File(s).getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());
            if (!AppUtil.listEqualsIgnoreOrder(s3ModelCodes, modelCodePresent)) {
                synchDB(s3ModelCodes, s3ModelCodes);
            }
            if (null != allKeysInDesiredBucket && !allKeysInDesiredBucket.isEmpty()) {
                for (CommonPrefix commonPrefix : allKeysInDesiredBucket) {
                    bucketKey = commonPrefix.prefix();
                    modelCode = new File(bucketKey).getName();
                    if (modelCodePresent.contains(modelCode)) {
                        log.info("[{}]: Model code [{}] found,skipping iteration", appName, modelCode);
                        continue;
                    }
                    objList = s3Service.getBucketObjects(bucketName, bucketKey);
                    if (null != objList && !objList.isEmpty()) {
                        for (S3Object object : AppUtil.skipFirst(objList)) {
                            Integer overlayId = overlayMasterMap.get(AppUtil.removeExtension(object.key()));
                            saveLayout(bucketName, object.key(), modelCode, overlayId);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("[{}]: Exception occurred while processing: error is: {}", appName, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

The snippet `List<ModelCode> modelCodes = layoutRepository.findDistinctAllBy();` the layoutRepository in this case is **ServiceA**, in a similar fashion it can be instance of ServiceB or ServiceC and so on.

so I am looking for way where I can isolate and overcome this tightly couple things form the code.

Please help

Answer (score 2):

So the only difference between all implementation are `List<ModelCode> modelCodes = layoutRepository.findDistinctAllBy()` ?

If yes, then does `ModelCode` is the same in all implementations ? If yes , you can simply just parameterised this method with `Supplier<List<ModelCode>>` and then make it as some kind of common function that can be reused :

```java
public void persistImageDetailsV2(Supplier<List<ModelCode>> modelCodeLoader) {
           ....
        try {
            fillMap();
            List<ModelCode> modelCodes = modelCodeLoader.get();
            List<String> modelCodePresent = modelCodes.stream().map(ModelCode::getModelCode)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            ....
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("[{}]: Exception occurred while processing: error is: {}", appName, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Then all the implementation just call this common method by :

```java
persistImageDetailsV2(()->layoutRepository.findDistinctAllBy());
persistImageDetailsV2(()->anotherLayoutRepository.findDistinctAllBy());
```

If `ModelCode` is not the same in all implementations , first extract an interface from them like :

```java
interface IModelCode {
   String getModelCode();
}
```

And make all ModeCode implementation implement this interface and the above common method will become :

```java
public <T extends IModelCode> void persistImageDetailsV2(Supplier<List<T>> modelCodeLoader) {
           ....
        try {
            fillMap();
            List<T> modelCodes = modelCodeLoader.get();
            List<String> modelCodePresent = modelCodes.stream().map(IModelCode::getModelCode)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            ....
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("[{}]: Exception occurred while processing: error is: {}", appName, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer the question, approach seems fine to me, I have posted one more issue while trying from my side, please help me out on the same, thanks